# Question about homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I have a question that asks the following:

> Let $S,*$ and $T,.$ be binary structures and let the there be a homomorphism betweeen the two. If this is surjective, then if $S$ is a group, so is $T$.

I don't understand what there is to prove. Isn't the definition of a homomorphism between two structures a map between the two structures? So if it's a homomorphism, if one is a ring, the other is a ring; if one is a field, the other is a field; etc.

Comment: We are given a map $f$ that satisfies $f(x*y)=f(x).f(y)$ ... If $f$ is merely surjective (not injective) and $S$ is a group, we must show that $T$ is also group.  For example, we must show that $.$ is associative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only hypothesis we are given is that these are two structures with binary operations. The fact that there is a homomorphism between them a priori implies nothing without knowing something about the homomorphism.

Some examples:

There is a homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_4$ into the multiplicative monoid of the Gaussian integers $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ sending a generator to $i$. This is not a ring homomorphism, it is only a group homomorphism, and the multiplicative monoid of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is not a group, even if we exclude $0$, because some elements don't have inverses.

There is a homomorphism from $\mathbb{Q}$ into $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ given by $1\mapsto 1$. Even though this is a ring homomorphism and $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field, $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is not a field.

There is a homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ into any group by sending $1$ to any element and extending accordingly. Even though $\mathbb{Z}$ is a ring, the group may not be a ring. Indeed, it need not even be the additive group of a ring because it may not be abelian.

There are many other examples.

Comment: So a homomorphism isn't a map between two structures then? I don't get it. All I have heard over and over again is that a homomorphism is a map between structures. I take it these structures don't have to be the same then? We can have homomorphisms that go from groups to rings, and it's still the same?

Comment: @user121615 Sure. An unqualified "homomorphism" doesn't mean all structure is preserved. As in the examples it could be a homomorphism with respect to only one binary operation when there is more than one, or the two operations may not have the same properties (and hence not be the same "type" of operation) but there could be a homomorphism anyway. As in GEdgar's comment above we just know that $f(x\ast y)=f(x).f(y)$. If $\ast$ is associative, this doesn't mean that $.$ is associative. Commutative also doesn't imply commutative, etc. The problem is to use surjectivity...

Comment: ...to show in this case that the axioms are preserved.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varphi:S\to T$ be your homomorphism. We need to check that $(T,\cdot)$ satisfies the axioms of a group.

- If $e$ is the identity of $S$, we need to show that $\varphi(e)$ is the identity of $T$.
- Since $\varphi(a)\varphi(a^{-1})=\varphi(e)$, we can show that every element of $T$ has an inverse ($\varphi$ is surjective).
- Associativity follows from the fact that
  $$
  (\varphi(a)\varphi(b))\varphi(c)=\varphi(ab)\varphi(c)=\varphi((ab)c)
  $$
  and $S$ has associativity.